# Could 'in some sense' be replaced with 'in some senses' without modifying the meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> All canonical clauses contain a subject, and the interpretation of
> subjectless non-canonical clauses always involves an ‘understood
> subject’ in some sense – for example, imperative *Speak up* and
> infinitival *Kim was ordered to leave* are interpreted with *you* and
> *Kim* as unexpressed subjects.

In the original, 'in some sense' seems to have the meaning of some kind of 'perception'(i.e . understanding). But, I think 'in some senses' also be proper with the 'meaning' definition: in my opinion,' in some cases' is also sensable,because there is 'for example' behind.

Comment: Is it one sense or many senses, for each understood subject?

Answer (score 0):

"In some sense" is an idiomatic expression meaning "in some way". The word "some" is used to indicate that the way is not clearly defined. It is possible, though uncommon, to use the plural "in some senses", meaning "in some ways". ... here, the meaning of "some" could indicate "not clearly defined, but could also mean "an unspecified number greater than one".

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20some%20sense%2Cin%20some%20senses%2Cin%20a%20way%2C%20in%20a%20sense&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows the relative frequency of use of various options.